# Having an issue running my python program in VS Code using open()

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am writing a Python program which reads data from a `.txt` file and writes to it. I am using VS Code as my editor and I am coming across an error where it doesn't recognize `infile = open("poem.txt", "r")` and tells me there is no such file or directory `poem.txt`. I can assure you it does exist and it is in the same folder. I can open the same program within IDLE and it runs fine. Is there a way to correct this error for VS Code without trying to hard code in absolute path for the file?

Comment: If you want to insure the program knows what directory to look in, why *wouldn't* you use the full path?

Comment: This limits it to MY path on MY computer. If I have someone else use the program and provide them with the files they would have to place it in the exact same path on their computer for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not hardcoded, but will change with the directory the program is run from:
Join constructs file paths from arguments, and getcwd gets the current working directory.

```
import os

infile = open(os.join(os.getcwd(), "poem.txt"), "r")
```